# Error while loading custom fonts in expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to load fonts in my expo managed project, I've followed the example given at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/ but it shows me this error
"Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

Here's my code for App.js

```react
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";

import LoginScreen from "./assets/Screens/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./assets/Screens/RegisterScreen";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const [isFontLoaded] = useFonts({
    nimbusBold: require("./assets/fonts/NimbusMonoPS-Bold.otf"),
    nimbusRegular: require("./assets/fonts/NimbusMonoPS-Regular.otf"),
  });

  if (!isFontLoaded) {
    return AppLoading;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Login"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Does anyone know why is this happening.
Thanks for precious time and answer in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Working Example here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/font-loading)

Firsly, run `npm i expo-font`

Then, run `npm i @expo-google-fonts/open-sans`

Then, run `npm i expo-app-loading`

Then in your project folder create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located.

in `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js` and inside that paste this code

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const useFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    Montserrat: require('../assets/fonts/Mulish.ttf'),
  });
};

export default useFonts;
```

Your `App.js` should look like this:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'; // This is must

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

import LoginScreen from './assets/screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './assets/screens/RegisterScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App(props) {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFontsAndRestoreToken = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFontsAndRestoreToken}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Login"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Your `LoginScreen.js` should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

function LoginScreen(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 30 }}>
        LoginScreen with fontFamily
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>LoginScreen without fontFamily</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
});
```

This is the best way to load fonts and I do it like this in all of my projects.

Comment: thank you brother for your help but i recently ran into an OS issue so all data is gone, but i will take care of it now.

Comment: If this answer helps you consider accepting it so that it may help others in the community

Comment: Yes,  this answer worked, but i realize when i upgraded my system some of the expo's dependencies got affected so i didn't get my output.

Comment: Check my updated answer. With all the latest expo dependencies.