# Too many re-renders. in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am making a custom TextInput component and in which i apply some different styles on the basis of state hook, which will be called onFocus and onBlur events, I've seen couple of solution on internet some of them are listed here [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265604/uncaught-invariant-violation-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-re)  and i tried some of them but none of them work for me.

NOTE: I am using Expo.

Screen.js

```
import InputField from '../Components/InputField'

const Screen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    return(
         <InputField 
              placeholder='user@example.com' 
              label='E-mail' 
              value={email} 
              setValue={setEmail()} 
              isSecure={false}
              defState={false}/>
    )

}
```

InputField.js

```
const InputField = ({placeholder, label, value, setValue, isSecure, defState}) => {

    const [isFocused, setFocus] = useState(!!defState)
    const [isBlur, setBlur] = useState(!!defState)

    const handle_focus = () => {
        console.log('focused')
        setFocus(true)
        setBlur(false)
    } 

    const handle_blur = () => {
        console.log('blur')
        setBlur(true)
        setFocus(false)
    }

    return (
        <View style={isBlur ? styles.container : styles.focusContainer}>
            {isFocused ? <Text style={styles.label}>{label}</Text>: null}
            <View style={styles.inputCont}>
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    secureTextEntry={isSecure}
                    value={value}
                    onChangeText={setValue}
                    onFocus={()=>handle_focus}
                    onBlur={()=>handle_blur}
                />
                <Icon name='checkmark-sharp' size={20} color={COLORS.blue} style={{marginLeft: 'auto'}}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `InputField` change this

```
onFocus={()=>handle_focus}
onBlur={()=>handle_blur}
```

To this

```
onFocus={() => handle_focus()}
onBlur={() => handle_blur()}
```

And also, in your `Screen` change this

```
setValue={setEmail()}
```

to This

```
setValue={(text) => setEmail(text)}
```

Comment: No it didn't worked, still i got the same error.

Comment: It worked but, there is a warning "[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Directory for /data/data/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%40rudrasoni%2FGaman/ExponentAsset-b3263095df30cb7db78c613e73f9499a.ttf doesn't exist."

Comment: Clear your `expo Go` cache, restart the server then again run in your Expo go App

Comment: Also I think you have not loaded your fonts correctly.. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67141441/error-while-loading-custom-fonts-in-expo-project) out. And make sure to load it this way..It is the simplest and most clear way of loading fonts...Also Check the working example that I gave in the answer

Comment: yes brother, I've done exactly how you described and it works perfectly fine. Thank you again.

Comment: @Rudrasoni Happy to Help! If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.